# VMware vmnet2 routes collide with en0

Tags: networking, vmware, vagrant, ifconfig

I am getting the following error when starting a vagrant box:

```
gajus:vagrant gajus$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'vmware_fusion' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'puppetlabs/centos-6.5-64-puppet' is up to date...
==> default: Verifying vmnet devices are healthy...
The VMware network device 'vmnet2' can't be started because
its routes collide with another device: 'en0'. Please
either fix the settings of the VMware network device or stop the
colliding device. Your machine can't be started while VMware
networking is broken.

Routing to the IP '192.168.1.0' should route through 'vmnet2', but
instead routes through 'en0'.
```

This is my ifconfig:

```
sh-3.2# ifconfig
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 60:03:08:a8:1e:ca
    inet6 fe80::6203:8ff:fea8:1eca%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4
    inet 192.168.1.175 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 72:00:01:ee:3a:20
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 72:00:01:ee:3a:21
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 02:03:08:a8:1e:ca
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1452
    ether 32:df:40:67:6a:63
    inet6 fe80::30df:40ff:fe67:6a63%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x8
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 62:03:08:8a:2b:00
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
```

Can anyone explain what is causing the issue and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue on OSX (10.10.2), running Vagrant 1.7.2 and VMWare Fusion 6.0.6, but I had the error message:

> Routing to the IP '192.168.1.0' should route through 'vmnet3', but
>   instead routes through 'en0'.

To fix this, I:

1. `cd /Library/Preferences/VMware\ Fusion`
2. Removed all mentions of `VMNET3` from `networking`. (before doing this,you should back the file up.)
3. `cd <where your Vagrantfile is>`
4. `vagrant up`

The VM was successfully brought up.